# FFImageLoading still caching image

Tags: xamarin.forms, ffimageloading

I set...

```
imgProfile.CacheType = FFImageLoading.Cache.CacheType.None;
imgProfile.CacheDuration = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Reinstall the app, load it once, switch to airplane mode, restart the app and the image is still there.

Surely it shouldn't be?

Comment: Are you closing the application? Or just sending it to background?

Comment: Closing. I tried it again and it's working as expected. So hopefully my silly mistake. Incidentally, where is the file stored? Is it in a location that's backed up to iCloud by the system?

Comment: You can read more here: https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/wiki/Advanced-Usage